# State Vectors relationship in Standard Lorentz Transformation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, inertial-frames

I am trying to properly understand relation (2.5.5) of Steven Weinberg's QFT.

In (2.5.2), It is shown that a state like $U(\Lambda)\Psi_{p,\sigma}$ has a momentum eigenvalue of ${\Lambda}p$. Consequently, it should generally be expanded in terms of all possible $\Lambda p$ state-vectors without any constraints on their $\sigma$ label, i.e. $$U(\Lambda)\Psi_{p,\sigma} = \sum_{\sigma^\prime} C_{\sigma \sigma^\prime} (\Lambda,p) \Psi_{\Lambda p,\sigma^\prime}\tag{2.5.3}.$$

Now the question: assume we have two momenta $k$ and $p$ related to each other through a Lorentz transformation $L$ in the form $p=Lk$. How could the following relation hold? In other words, why do we have the constraint not to include all possible $\sigma$ labels in the following expansion?

$$ U(L) \Psi_{k,\sigma} = \frac{1}{N(p)} \Psi_{Lk,\sigma}$$

Is this some sort of a definition (or constraint) that we are introducing to study the consequences? In other words, is this in fact the definition of "Standard Lorentz Transformation"?

Comment: yes, you are right the momentum on the right hand side should be $p=Lk$.

Answer (score -1):

$\Psi_{p,\sigma} = U(L(p)) \Psi_{k,\sigma}$ is a *definition* for the state $\Psi_{p,\sigma}$. This formula does not apply to *any* two momenta or for any $L(p)$. You *choose* a reference momentum $k$ and you *choose* an $L(p)$ such that $L(p)k=p$ and then you *define* $\Psi_{p,\sigma}$ as shown above.

Comment: The question is: why have we assumed the discrete quantum label does not change for such a transformation while, generally, we should not assume such a thing, should we?

Comment: It's not an assumption. It's a _definition_! $\Psi_{k,\sigma} = U(L(p)) \Psi_{k,\sigma}$ defines the discrete label $\sigma$.

Comment: This cannot be a definition of the discrete quantum label. This can, at best, be a definition of the standard Lorentz transformation as a Lorentz Trans whose operator representation does not affect the quantum discrete label. Still, you have not given your opinion on this argument: there is no implicit or explicit constraint on a Lorentz tran not to change discrete quantum labels, is there? If your agree, then the next question is what is special about the standard Lorentz tranformation that keeps these labels invariant? Pay attention i am not talking about the little group.

Comment: @moha - There is nothing special about the standard Lorentz transformation. We have chosen to define the $\sigma$ label on the state $\Psi_{p,\sigma}$ by _identifying_ it with the $\sigma$ label on the reference state $\Psi_{k,\sigma}$. Note that the $\sigma$ label on $\Psi_{k,\sigma}$ hasn't been defined yet (and that's where the little group will come in), but what we have done here is defined the $\sigma$ label on all other states _in terms of_ the reference state.

Comment: @moha - You are thinking of the equation $\Psi_{p,\sigma} = U(L(p)) \Psi_{k,\sigma}$ as a constraint on $L(p)$. Instead you should think of it as an equation which constrains the $\sigma$ label on $\Psi_{p,\sigma}$ and matches/identifies it with the $\sigma$ label on $\Psi_{k,\sigma}$.

Comment: @moha The next step of the derivation is to then explain what the $\sigma$ label on $\Psi_{k,\sigma}$ means. This is done by looking at the little group and its representations.